# Why does the loss of vgg16 equal nan, but performs normally when adding an extra Softmax layer?

Tags: tensorflow, softmax, vgg-net

I am coding a vgg16 net with Tensorflow low-level api. The model is test in imagenet12 dataset. Due to computation cost, I split the validation set into 80% training data and 20% test data.

First, the last layer `fc8` outputs without the activation of `softmax`, and I use the `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels, logits)` to compute the loss. It finally outputs `nan` in the training process.

Then I try to add a `softmax` layer under `fc8`, but still use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels, logits)` to compute the loss. Surprisingly, the loss outputs normally rather than `nan`.

Here is the code before adding `softmax` layer:

```
def vgg16(): 
    ...
    fc8_layer = FullConnectedLayer(y, self.weight_dict, regularizer_fc=self.regularizer_fc)
    self.op_logits = fc8_layer.layer_output

def loss(self):
    entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=self.Y, logits=self.op_logits)
    l2_loss = tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()

    self.op_loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy, name='loss') + l2_loss
```

and I change the vgg16 output like:

```
def vgg16(): 
    ...
    fc8_layer = FullConnectedLayer(y, self.weight_dict, regularizer_fc=self.regularizer_fc)
    self.op_logits = tf.nn.softmax(fc8_layer.layer_output)
```

Besides, here is my optimizer:

```
def optimize(self):
    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
                self.opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=self.config.learning_rate, momentum=0.9,
                                                      use_nesterov=True)
                self.op_opt = self.opt.minimize(self.op_loss)
```

I don't understand why adding a softmax layer works. In my idea, two softmax layers wont affect the final loss, since it doesn't change the proportion of each output unit.

Comment: Yes, this is strange. Reading the doc:  `**WARNING:** This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax on logits internally for efficiency.  Do not call this op with the  output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results.` So the case producing the NaN is actually the correct usage of the function.

Comment: Yep. Now I am think if it because the initialized values that produce ```nan``` loss. At the beginning, I use the parameters extracted from ```keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16``` for conv layers, and initialized parameters of fc layers with normal distribution. Then I try to initialize all params from ```keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16```, it works and doesn't output ```nan``` when I set suiable learning rate and regularizer.

Comment: @StefanDragnev I agree that. However, I think theoretically two softmax layers wont change the final loss. It is still a little strange ╥﹏╥.